# What does the get and put function do?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, state-monad

From [our lecture notes](https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/~324/lec/lec11/slides11.pdf):

```
get' state = (state, state)
put' item state = ((), item)     -- () is void value

data State s a = State (s -> (a, s))

-- Functions get and put:        -- (sic!)

get :: State s s
get = State get'

put :: s -> State s ()
put item = State (put' item)
```

I am totally lost in these two functions `get` and `put`.

First, there is no arrow in the type signature of `get`:

```
get :: State s s
```

What does it mean?

What does `s` mean in both `get` and `put`? Are they state?

Comment: `State a b` means a `State` that stores a state of type `a`, and "returns" an element of type `b`, so for `get` you query the state, hence it returns the state so in that case `b ~ a`. `get'` and `put'` are defined on page 32 of the slides.

Comment: yes, `s` is the mnemonic for "state".

Comment: There is no arrow in the type signature because `get` is not a function. That's all it means.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "a state that stores a state"?? this bound to be confusing.

Comment: @WillNess: well I think it is a bit unfortunate nomenclature in the first place, since an item of type `State` itself does not stores a state, it basically is a "transition" between `State`s (a transition that can be a no-op), but not really a `State` itself :).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem we can just not skimp on words and say " 'State' monadic value representing a state-altering-and-passing-computation"... :)  or "State monad action", or something...

Comment: @melpomene If `get` is not a function, then what is it? I tried to google the definition of Haskell function. But it just comes up with a bunch of examples.

Comment: @user8314628 no, it is a function. and it is a value. Haskell is ambivalent that way. You should have included more code in your question, like, the definition of `State`.

Comment: @user8314628 If I do `get = ["fetch", "my", "stuff"]`, what is `get`? Well, it's a list of strings (or `[String]`). Similarly, your `get` is a value of type `State s s`. Or if I were to do `foo = Nothing`, then `foo` would be not a function but a value of type `Maybe s`.

Comment: @melpomene but  the value of type `State s a` is actually a function of type `s -> (a, s)`, isn't it.

Comment: @WillNess Absolutely not. A value of type `State s a` *has* a function of type `s -> (a,s)` in it, but it isn't itself one.

Comment: @DanielWagner context is everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `State s a` is essentially a function `s -> (a, s)`, that is, a function that takes a state and returns a value of some type `a` and a new state.

So `get :: State s s` is a `s -> (s, s)`, a function that simply returns the current state.

`put :: s -> s -> ((), s)` is implemented as `s -> _ -> ((), s)`, a function that takes a given state, ignores the current state, returns the given state, and produces no new values.

Comment: but the function `s -> (s, s)` "simply returns" a tuple, no?

Comment: @WillNess yes it returns a tuple where both members are the current state. The first member of this tuple is the value that you can fmap/>>= over, and the second member is the state that is being threaded and will be given to the next stateful step. It just so happens that in `get` both members are the same. We return the current state to be fmap'd over, and also pass it to the next stateful step.

Comment: I was trying to point out a part of the answer which I thought would be very confusing for a newbie.

Comment: `get :: State s` is a function that simply returns the current state. So the function `get` takes no argument and return a value, and `State s s` is the type of the return value?